# laravel 4.2 blade @include not getting parsed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, partials, laravel-blade

I have a view in `app/views/myview.blade.php'.

In it I have some markup and 2 `@include` statements.

`@include('partners.xyx.common.configuration_container')`

this one works, then I have another one.

```
@include('partners.xyz.common.configuration_saver_scripts', [
   'appEndPoint' => 'abc'
])
```

and this one doesn't get parsed, and shows up as is, without any error. Is there something wrong with the way I am passing the variable?

Comment: I just tried your include code in one of my templates (changing the path to something existent, obviously), and it works. You do have a `.blade.php` extension on your template, right?

Comment: yes I do. I figured it out actually, I put all of the statement on one line and it started working.